# изменение бэкграунда дива при навидении на список который находится в этом диве

Tags: css, css3, html5, hover, background

В общем у меня есть div в котором есть ul>li*X>ul>li*X. Мне нужно чтоб когда я наводился на li первого уровня, то задний фон ( а точнее картинка ) дива менялась в зависимости от того, на какой именно li я наведу.

Я пытался все сделать с помощью CSS :

```css
a,ul,li,ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {}

li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div.topNavCat {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

ul.menu {}

ul.menu li {}

ul.submenu {}

ul.submenu li {}

ul.menu li:hover div.topNavCat {
  background-color: blue;
}


/** я пытался еще менять местами ul.menu li:hover и div.topNavCat но тогда меняет цвет сам ul **/
```

```html
<div class="topNavCat">
  <ul class="menu"><a href="#">MENU</a>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как при наведении на один элемент менять стили другого элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293281/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: На css так не получиться.

Comment: @СашаБоричевский в том вопросе меняется дочерние элемент, в этом вопросе надо менять стиль родителя. PS: сделать только через JS.

Comment: Сделал пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d2h6de25/. Это не универсальное решение.

Comment: если не на CSS то как можно, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, то так

```js
var mainLi = document.querySelectorAll('.main-li'); /*хватаем все главные li*/
var topNavCat =document.querySelector('.topNavCat');/*хватаем div*/
var backgrounds = ['#effeee','#f0000e','#5fda55'];/*создаем массив background с цветами*/
for(let i = 0; i < mainLi.length ; i++){ /*главные li прокручиваем их в цикле*/

mainLi[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){ /*и при наведении меняем цвет  дива в зависмости от того куда была  наведена мышь*/
    topNavCat.style.background = backgrounds[i];
    e.stopPropagation();
},true)
mainLi[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){ /*а когда убираем цвет div поумолчанию*/
    topNavCat.style.background = 'aqua';
    e.stopPropagation();
},true)
}
```

```css
a,ul,li,ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {}

li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div.topNavCat {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.main-li{background:green;}/*это для нагладности надо убрать*/
ul.menu {}

ul.menu li {}

ul.submenu {}

ul.submenu li {}




/** я пытался еще менять местами ul.menu li:hover и div.topNavCat но тогда меняет цвет сам ul **/
```

```html
<div class="topNavCat">
  <ul class="menu"><a href="#">MENU</a>
    <li class="main-li">LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-li">LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-li">LOREM IPSUM
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    a,ul,li,ol {
      list-style-type: none;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .topNavCat {
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
    ul.menu > li {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    ul.menu > li.nav-background {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      background-color: aqua;
      transition: background-color .3s;
    }

    ul.menu > li:first-child:hover ~ li.nav-background {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    ul.menu > li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li.nav-background {
      background-color: red;
    }
    ul.menu > li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li.nav-background {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="topNavCat">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>LOREM IPSUM
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>LOREM IPSUM
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>LOREM IPSUM
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='nav-background'></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Это с доп. элементом, можно в принципе сделать и без него, используя `::before` или `::after`