# Изменение стиля при наведении

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте! Допустим есть два дива:

```
 <div class='block1'>...</div>

 <div class='block2'>...</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении (`hover`) на блок `block1` изменялся стиль `block2`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475933/270124

Comment: @splash58, в моем случае у блоков разные родители

Answer (score 2):

```
const elem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('block1')[0];
elem1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('block2')[0].style.example = 'property'
})
elem1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('block2')[0].style.example = ''
})
```