# Как изменить элемент при движении мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Как изменить элемент при движении мыши? Как получить координаты мыши и отследить, что они изменяются? И исходя из этого, допустим, изменить элемент?

Comment: `addEventListener(“mousemove”, function(e){console.log(e.x,e.y)})`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как при наведении на один элемент менять стили другого элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293281/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a onmouseover='alert("Mouse is over it!")'>Some text</a>
```